# Is there an API to automatically pop up virtual keyboard on windows 8 or windows 10 touch laptop by win32 application

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-10

I am running a win32 application on windows touch laptop, I want to programmatically display virtual keyboard, if someone taps on a text input area.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the on-screen keyboard in Windows 8 it shows up automatically when a text box receives focus, so long as it has been enabled to do so in PC Settings.

Answer (score 0):

It did pop up automatically until recently. Now this week you have to manually hit the touch screen keyboard icon in the notifications area to make it appear. Some settings must have changed  when my laptop did a windows update last week.

Comment: If you are talking about updates for Windows 10 then you may be able to bring this [auto popup behavior back](http://www.windowscentral.com/auto-display-touch-keyboard-windows-10-desktop-mode).